# Adjust TOC title font, size and weight using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to use the `tocloft` package to make some adjustments to my TOC. This MWE is based on [the accepted answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16032/how-do-i-indent-the-2nd-line-a-long-chapter-name-created-using-the-tocloft-packa).

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Book Antiqua}  
\setsansfont{Liberation Sans} %!Change to any font that you have on your system

\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{\baselineskip}      % allow spacing after each chapter/section entry
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
%\addto\captionsenglish{\def\contentsname{Contents}} %! Needed for babel? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35903/formatting-the-title-of-the-toc
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries} %!some command to make the heading large, bold and sans
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-0.25in}        % Title is 1in from top
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{2.0\baselineskip}% 1 double space after title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill}               % Blank space before title
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}              % Blank space after title
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}                         % Can make it bold faced here; don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}             % Puts dots after chapter entries
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter\ }             %
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{}                    % Don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}%
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}                      %
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{1in}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{A really long chapter heading that will wrap around in the table of contents and end up inline with the chapter name}
\section{First section}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

From [the documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf), I would have thought that `\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}` would have set the title to bold and large.
What am I getting wrong here?

Also, I would like to make sure that the title font and entry fonts are set to my sans font. Is there something more I have to do for that? Maybe `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries\sffamily}`?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Book Antiqua` font has a bold version? The font is clearly not a sans - serif font.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm quite new to LaTeX, but this font specification is meeting my purposes. The headings are defined by `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}` and the body of the text by `\setmainfont{Book Antiqua}`. The bold in the body come out as bold `Book Aniqua`. I suspect that I need to do more reading on this?

Comment: Well, there is a second `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill}` (right in the middle of the bunch of `\cft....` redefinitions) after your first redefinition, so you're wiping out the first setting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original code has

```
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries} %!some command to make the heading huge and bold
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-0.25in}        % Title is 1in from top
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{2.0\baselineskip}% 1 double space after title
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill}               % Blank space before title
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}              % Blank space after title
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}
```

So any font change for the title or the chapter toc entries is not used. Setting them to `\hfill\Large\bfseries\sffamily` etc. will change to large, bold sans serif entries, given that the font supports those settings.

Similar modifications must be applied to `\cftsecfont` etc, if desired.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}



\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Book Antiqua}  
\setsansfont{Liberation Sans} %Change to any font that you have on your system

\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}


\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{\baselineskip}      % allow spacing after each chapter/section entry
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\contentsname{Contents}} %! Needed for babel? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35903/formatting-the-title-of-the-toc
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries\sffamily} %!some command to make the heading huge and bold
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-0.25in}        % Title is 1in from top
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{2.0\baselineskip}% 1 double space after title
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}                         % Can make it bold faced here; don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}                         % Can make it bold faced here; don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}             % Puts dots after chapter entries
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter\ }             %
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{}                    % Don't put a space in the {}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}%
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}                      %
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{1in}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}


\begin{document}



\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{A really long chapter heading that will wrap around in the table of contents and end up inline with the chapter name}
\section{First section}

\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to switch to `Liberation Sans` since I don't have `TeX Gyre Heros` on my computer

Comment: I'll edit the question to use `Liberation Sans`. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Simon: You're welcome. Happy TeXing.